# How to self-reference column in pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

In Python's Pandas, I am using the Data Frame as such:

```
drinks = pandas.read_csv(data_url)
```

Where data_url is a string URL to a CSV file

When indexing the frame for all "light drinkers" where light drinkers is constituted by 1 drink, the following is written:

```
drinks.light_drinker[drinks.light_drinker == 1]
```

Is there a more DRY-like way to self-reference the "parent"? I.e. something like:

```
drinks.light_drinker[self == 1]
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 8):

You can now use [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas-dataframe-query) or [assign](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) depending on what you need:

```
drinks.query('light_drinker == 1')
```

or to mutate the the df:

```
df.assign(strong_drinker = lambda x: x.light_drinker + 100)
```

**Old answer**

Not at the moment, but an enhancement with your ideas is being discussed [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9239). For simple cases `where` might be enough. The new API might look like this:

```
df.set(new_column=lambda self: self.light_drinker*2)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the most current version of pandas, `.where()` also accepts a callable!

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html?highlight=where#pandas.DataFrame.where

So, the following is now possible:

```
drinks.light_drinker.where(lambda x: x == 1)
```

which is particularly useful in method-chains. However, this will return only the Series (not the DataFrame filtered based on the values in the `light_drinker` column). This is consistent with your question, but I will elaborate for the other case.

To get a filtered DataFrame, use:

```
drinks.where(lambda x: x.light_drinker == 1)
```

Note that this will keep the shape of the self (meaning you will have rows where all entries will be `NaN`, because the condition failed for the `light_drinker` value at that index).

If you don't want to preserve the shape of the DataFrame (i.e you wish to drop the `NaN` rows), use:

```
drinks.query('light_drinker == 1')
```

Note that the items in `DataFrame.index` and `DataFrame.columns` are placed in the `query` namespace by default, meaning that you don't have to reference the self.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to reference parent objects like `self` or `this` in Pandas, but perhaps another way of doing what you want which could be considered more DRY is `where()`.

```
drinks.where(drinks.light_drinker == 1, inplace=True)
```