# Pandas - Self reference of instances in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF

```
 SampleID ParentID
0  S10        S20    
1  S10        S30    
2  S20        S40     
3  S30              
4  S40
```

How can I put the id of the other row in the column 'ParentID' instead of the string?

Expected result:

```
 SampleID ParentID 
0  S10        2    
1  S10        3    
2  S20        4   
3  S30              
4  S40
```

The closest result I found for this problem was:
[How to self-reference column in pandas Data Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101317/how-to-self-reference-column-in-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: what have you tried? check out http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Comment: I don't want to replace the string by any text. What I've tried was to reset the index to `SampleID` and use `df.loc[ParentID]` but then I couldn't retrieve the previous id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and then assign column `index`:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df[['SampleID']].reset_index(), 
               df[['ParentID']], 
               left_on='SampleID',
               right_on='ParentID')
print (df1)
   index SampleID ParentID
0      2      S20      S20
1      3      S30      S30
2      4      S40      S40

df['ParentID'] = df1['index']
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
print (df)
  SampleID ParentID
0      S10        2
1      S10        3
2      S20        4
3      S30         
4      S40
```

---

Another solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and `dict` where swap keys with values:

```
d = dict((v,k) for k,v in df.SampleID.iteritems())
print (d)
{'S10': 1, 'S40': 4, 'S20': 2, 'S30': 3}

df.ParentID = df.ParentID.map(d)
df.ParentID.fillna('', inplace=True)
print (df)
  SampleID ParentID
0      S10        2
1      S10        3
2      S20        4
3      S30         
4      S40
```

Comment: Uh, I really liked the map one!!! I use a lot of javascript and I used some map/reduce for school projects for 'big data' problems and mapping is a common practice. For this reason this seems clearer to me even though the merge is also clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace` by passing along the mapping lists of values to replace:

```
df.ParentID.replace(df.SampleID.tolist(), df.index.tolist(), inplace=True)

df
Out[22]: 
  SampleID  ParentID
0      S10       2.0
1      S10       3.0
2      S20       4.0
3      S30       NaN
4      S40       NaN
```

Comment: This didn't work. It gave an error saying about comparing strings and ndarray `TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'
`

Comment: it's inplace so if you run it twice, you very likely get a dumb answer the second time because the mapping is already done

Comment: That's true. I read the csv file again and it didn't throw an error. It seems much slower, though. It's been running for a while and no response so far. I think the .tolist() transformation is what makes the process slow